# Anti-fungal after pruning a honey locust?

Tags: pruning, fungus, honey-locust

I recently had two companies give me quotes on pruning the deadwood from my large honey locust tree.

Company A was marketing itself as stronger in tree health, and they boasted spraying anti-fungal on the freshly-cut limbs, claiming honey locusts are susceptible to fungal infections.

Company B said that they have found this spraying to be ineffective and don't recommend it.  They are more of a run-of-the-mill trimming company but they're passionate and climber-only.

I have not found any discussion either way in my Interwebs search.  Does anyone have any insight or references?

**EDIT:** I am in the northern Midwest of the United States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say where you are in the world, but the best time to prune Gleditsia triancanthos is actually autumn/fall - cutting live wood in spring is  likely to mean bleeding of sap from the cuts. However, if all you're having done is the dead wood removed, that might not be such a problem.

I can't find  anything that suggests these trees are any more prone to fungal infection than other plants, though are prone to insect damage on leaves, so it sounds to me like the fungal treatment they're intending to use is likely extra to requirements. Further info on pruning these here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/trim-gleditsia-sunburst-tree-75180.html

Comment: Apologies -- updated the question with my location.  And yes, the pruning is only for dead wood so I assumed there would be minimal sap bleeding.

Comment: @calcium3000  Honey locust do not bleed like maples and respond well to pruning so I agree that fungal treatment is an extra"

Comment: Company A is trying to get more money from you - I'm sure that'll spray an anti-fungal on the wounds, but it will have zero effect on the tree.